# Firebase Read Operation Calculation

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

When I use .collection().doc() and specify a document id. Resulting in getting only one document from the collection, does this operation count as one read or as reading all of the documents in the firestore database?

```
StreamBuilder(
              stream: firestore
              .collection('users')
              .doc(auth.currentUser!.uid)
              .snapshots(),
```

Additional Question: The .where() query reads all the documents in the collection right? So the total reads is not the amount of documents I get as a result of the query but the total amount of documents in the collection? Thank you.

Comment: No problem https://cloud.google.com/firestore/pricing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only charged for the documents that you read from/on the server. Since you only read one document, it's charged as one read (plus any charges for the bandwidth required to transfer the data).

A query does **not** read all documents in a collection, but instead uses one or more indexes to determine what documents to read. You are not charged explicitly for those index reads, unless there are no results for a query: in that case you get charged for one document read.